# Value controller usage ? Web-Api with mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

i started to work my way around with webapi value controller . I had a requirement of displaying a 5 dropdowns may be more in future on my view .

The thing i understood using API controller is we can have one GEt,PUT etc in single API CONTROLLER . When i need to get the data into my multiple dropdowns on MY VIEW .

Do i need to have 'N' API controllers for 'N' drop down Lists becoz i can have one GET in each API controller where i get data from db to bind it to dropdown .

Is there any alternate work around .

Its been easy sort of thing with normal controller as i used to use model binding and also it can return view where in contrast API wont :)

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also return complex data from a single `GET` action in WebAPI. Just create a class that contains a property with the data for each dropdown and have the `Get` method return an instance of this class. You will typically receive this as JSON data so you can sort it in the web page. 
This will also mean that you only have to make one request instead of several requests in order to fill the dropdowns.

However, if the data is not related in any way it might be better to create several controllers that each return the data for a specific dropdown.

Comment: ooh cool mate that's exactly what i am looking for :) that's helpful . Is there any sort of articles i can look into it . Like how they are doing on view after instance is returned as json. 
Regards

Comment: @supercool: handling on view is done by JavaScript/jquery. Sorry, I'm not too experienced in that matter.

Comment: yeah i will look into it :) anyway your answer is good to move and explore . I hope it should do :) thanks buddie